# CalDav: Different category assignment in Nextcloud and Thunderbird Lightning

Tags: calendar, thunderbird, caldav, nextcloud, lightning

If creating an Event via the nextcloud Ui, the Caldav server response looks like this (output shortened):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0

PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN

BEGIN:VTIMEZONE

TZID:Europe/Berlin

BEGIN:DAYLIGHT

TZOFFSETFROM:+0100

TZOFFSETTO:+0200

TZNAME:CEST

DTSTART:19700329T020000

RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3

END:DAYLIGHT

BEGIN:STANDARD

SUMMARY:Test
.....

CATEGORIES:Jg. 5  <-- // here

CATEGORIES:Jg. 6  <-- // here

....

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

If the event is created in Thunderbird it looks like this (output shortened):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR

VERSION:2.0

CALSCALE:GREGORIAN

PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN

DTSTART:19700329T020000

RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU

DTSTART:19701025T030000

RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU

END:STANDARD

END:VTIMEZONE

BEGIN:VEVENT

CREATED:20200813T111910Z

LAST-MODIFIED:20200817T084432Z

DTSTAMP:20200817T084432Z

UID:584589d3-54a6-4f5a-bd4c-03e478938b07

SUMMARY:Test

CATEGORIES:Jg. 5,Jg. 6 <-- // here

....    
END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR
```

As you can see, Nextcloud creates for each category it's own field, while Thunderbird separates each category with a comma (,).

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [rfc 5545 section 3.8.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.2), the `CATEGORIES` property can have multiple, comma-separated values. This is what Thunderbird does.

At the same time, there are a number of rfc 5545 properties that are allowed to be specified more than once, e.g. `ATTENDEE`. Therefore parsers have learned to deal with multiple properties. Looking at [rfc 7986 section 5.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7986#section-5.6), multiple properties for `CATEGORIES` are explicitly allowed.

It is possible that some parsers may internally turn multiple `CATEGORIES` properties into a single one (or vice versa?), which would be noticeable when editing the event.